# How to speed up PowerShell operations on AD objects

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script for work that will query all of our AD domains and then return the computers that have admin privileges. The below script works and returns the expected results but it is very slow on our larger domains.

When working with 23k objects and less it runs in only a few minutes (6min or so), but when its has to handle 90k+ it gets into hours.

I am new to PowerShell and have no idea what operation here would have an exponential runtime increase so I have been unable to narrow it down. My hunch is that it has to deal with that way PowerShell is expanding the arrays to continuously add more objects? I was also thinking about making better use of the pipeline... but being new and coming from bash I am unfamiliar with this concept and how to utilize it in this code

Is there a way I can speed this up to run faster than a few hours? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$date = Get-Date -uFormat %d-%m-%y

ForEach($domain in $domains)
{
        $all_computers = Get-ADComputer -Server $domain -filter * -Properties enabled | select-object name,enabled,@{name="distinguishedname";expression={$_.DistinguishedName -replace "(CN[^,]+,)"}}
        #Gets all of the objects that are in a group and pulls their names this is to get the admin flag that is appended to names in this group
        $group_name = (Get-ADGroup -Server $domain -Filter{name -like "*admin*"}).Name

        #Counts the devices pulled from the computer query
        $DevNum = $all_computers.count
        echo "Number of devices: " $DevNum > "$domain LARGE $date.txt"

        #Remove servers from the list
        $all_computers = $all_computers | ?{ $_ -NotMatch "Servers" }

        #Counts the number of servers we removed
        $NumSkipped = $DevNum - $all_computers.count

        Switch($all_computers){
            #Finding all of the accounts where both types of admins exist and removing them from the master list
            {$group_name -contains $($_.name + "Admins") -and $group_name -contains $($_.name + "UPEPAdmins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype"  "both";Continue}
            #Finding all of the accounts with only exception admins and removing them from the master list
            {$group_name -contains $($_.name + "Admins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "old";Continue}
            #Finding all of the accounts with only upep admins and removing them from the master list
            {$group_name -contains $($_.name + "UPEPAdmins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "UPEP";Continue}
            #These accounts have no admin
            default {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "No"}
        }

        echo "Number of servers skipped: " $NumSkipped >> "$domain LARGE $date.txt"

        echo "Number of workstations: " $all_computers.count >> "$domain LARGE $date.txt"

        echo "Number of Exception admins found: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -match "old|both"}).count >> "$domain LARGE $date.txt"

        echo "Number of UPEP admins found: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -match "upep|both"}).count >> "$domain LARGE $date.txt"

        echo "Number of both UPEP and Exception admins found: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -eq "both"}).count >> "$domain LARGE $date.txt" 

        #output
        $all_computers | Export-Csv "$domain LARGE $date.csv"
}
```

## Edit 1:

Updated code to reflect suggestions from SodaWillow, TheMadTechnician, and
removing trim and replacing it with -replace decreased runtime by a little bit.

## Edit 2:

Updated the code to the correct solution, ontop of TheMadTechnician's suggestions I filtered the groups to decrease their number and also inserted group names into an array rather than a table. The use of an array sped up operations significantly when combined with the decreased group numbers.

Current bugs:  The "Both" admin types are being exported to CSV correctly but not being reported in the text file at all, I think it has to do with the logic in the if statement. I am looking at that currently

## Edit 3:

Fixed Both admin type logic bug, this is the final solution for this problem.
the $domains var is declared out of view of this code block due to private information.

Thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: You may want to try LDAP filters and `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` (examples here : http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Getting_usernames_from_active_directory_with_powershell). Measure the time consumed by each part of your code to find the longest queries, and then begin by optimizing those ones (if you haven't done this already)

Comment: I have tried to run through and use Measure-Command on chunks of code to see where I may be adding unnecessary time. Nothing seems to be excessive but when put together take a really long time

Comment: I would have imagined L2 and L4 lasting much longer than the rest. L4 could be rewritten with `Get-ADGroup` maybe ?

Comment: Yea, those take a hot second. a few minutes a piece. but nothing unreasonable. It looks like the trim (L28 & L37) are the heavy hitters, would replace work in place of trim with that sub expression?

The reason I did not just use get-adgroup is because the information I need for metrics is split between adcomputer and ad group due to poor AD organization.

Comment: There is a LOT of processing afterwards, that needs to be completely broken down and understood to optimize the script. I'll try to dive in :).

Comment: Okay, I am also currently working through each line as well I will update my question if I find anything!

And yea,the extra processing is because they want this is a specific format for metrics reports and SQL server dumps. 

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Well, I got your point about the `Trim` thingie and I guess `Replace` could do the trick, combined with the very nice answer from TheMadTechnician you will definitely change things :).

Comment: Another approach : between 23k and 90k objects, where do things get nasty ?

Comment: I wish I knew, our Domain size jumps from 23k to 97k, 97k being our largest and 23k being second largest.

Comment: So, from 4hrs down to 30mins ? Not bad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like at the least you could benefit from combining some lines. There's a few places that you define a variable, and then immediately redefine it by filtering itself. Such as:

```
$servs = $all_computers | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName
$servs = $servs -Match "Servers"
```

Can be reduced to:

```
$servs = $all_computers | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName | Where {$_ -match "Servers"}
```

Now do that same thing for `$admin_exist_cnt` and `$upep_admin_exist_cnt`

```
$admin_exist_cnt = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $group_name -ReferenceObject $com_name_admin -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -Property name | select-object @{name="name";expression={$($_.name).toString().TrimEnd("A","d","m","i","n","s")}}
```

and

```
$upep_admin_exist_cnt = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $group_name -ReferenceObject $com_name_upep -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -Property name | Select-Object @{name="name";expression={$($_.Name).ToString().TrimEnd("U","P","E","P","A","d","m","i","n","s")}}
```

Then near the end you run through all the computers looking for "both" admintypes, and remove those from the `$all_computers` variable, then run through the whole thing again, and do that like 4 times. No, don't do that, use the `Switch` command instead. It would look like this:

```
Switch($all_computers){
    #Finding all of the accounts where both types of admins exist and removing them from the master list
    {$both_exist_cnt.name -contains $_.name} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype"  "both";Continue}
    #Finding all of the accounts with only exception admins and removing them from the master list
    {$admin_exist_cnt.name -contains $_.name} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "old";Continue}
    #Finding all of the accounts with only upep admins and removing them from the master list
    {$upep_admin_exist_cnt.name -contains $_.name} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "UPEP";Continue}
    #These accounts have no admin
    default {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "No"}
}
```

Then you can reduce the output section to just:

```
#output
$all_computers | Export-Csv test.csv
```

**Edit:** Ok, went back over things and saw that you're redefining things a whole lot. Instead I propose just running it through a `Switch` once, then counting up your results afterwards. This will reduce memory consumption considerably, which may not matter on small test runs but should make a considerable difference when running against large quantities. Try this revised script, and let me know if you have any specific questions:

```
#TODO Fix the server thing and put it in a for loop
$all_computers = Get-ADComputer -Server NW -filter * -Properties enabled | select name,enabled,distinguishedname
#Gets all of the objects that are in a group and pulls their names this is to get the admin flag that is appended to names in this group
$group_name = Get-ADObject -Server NW -Filter{objectCategory -eq "group"} | select name

#Counts the devices pulled from the computer query
#TODO Replace "test.txt" with a descriptive file name
$DevNum = $all_computers.count
echo "Number of devices: " $DevNum > test.txt

#Remove servers from the list
$all_computers = $all_computers | ?{ $_ -NotMatch "Servers" }

#Counts the number of servers we removed
$NumSkipped = $DevNum - $all_computers.count

Switch($all_computers){
    #Finding all of the accounts where both types of admins exist and removing them from the master list
    {$group_name.name -contains $($_.name + "Admins") -and $group_name.name -contains $($_.name + "UPEPAdmins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype"  "both";Continue}
    #Finding all of the accounts with only exception admins and removing them from the master list
    {$group_name.name -contains $($_.name + "Admins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "old";Continue}
    #Finding all of the accounts with only upep admins and removing them from the master list
    {$group_name.name -contains $($_.name + "UPEPAdmins")} {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "UPEP";Continue}
    #These accounts have no admin
    default {$_ | Add-Member "admintype" "No"}
}

#TODO Replace "test.txt" with a descriptive file name
echo "Number of servers skipped: " $NumSkipped >> test.txt

#Calculating the number of workstations 
echo "Number of workstations: " $all_computers.count >> test.txt

#TODO Replace "test.txt" with a descriptive file name
echo "Number of Exception admins found: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -match "old|both"}).count >> test.txt

#TODO Replace "test.txt" with a descriptive file name
echo "Number of UPEP admins found: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -match "upep|both"}).count >> test.txt

#Find both exception and upep admin names
if($($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -ne "No"}))
{
        echo "Number of both UPEP and Exception Admins: 0" >> test.txt
}else
{
        echo "Number of both UPEP and Exception Admins: " $($all_computers|?{$_.admintype -match "both"}).count >> test.txt
}

#output
$all_computers | Export-Csv test.csv
```

Comment: I made your changes on a branch of the script and have ran it on a test bed server several times, on average it has increased running time by 6 seconds (to 36 seconds). Where as the previous iteration on the test bed server was able to complete in 30 seconds. Is there something in the switch statement that would scale better than what I was doing because you lose the overhead of redefining the variables?

Also, thank you for your time and help I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I re-read your script and I'm making some serious changes and will get back to you. I think there's definitely some improvements that can be done to speed it up and help manage memory for larger iterations.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. 

Just a heads up, I removed the trim command and replaced it with -replace 

`$upep_admin_exist_cnt = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $group_name -ReferenceObject $com_name_upep -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -Property name | Select-Object @{name="name";expression={$($_.Name).ToString() -replace "UPEPAdmins"}}`

Is now what it looks like and I will update my question to reflect your current suggestions and my changes!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once, really nice effort. Maybe you could give it a try on http://codereview.stackexchange.com since the script is already working pretty well, though it seems to me a script running for hours is kind of an issue to me :) I'm really curious about the results of this on a very large scale.

Comment: I've never used codereview.stackexchange.com, I'm not familiar with it, but I'll have to check it out. Yeah, last script I had that ran for hours was dealing with almost 700k server objects, every group they touched (nested, and nested in), and all of the other members of those groups.

Comment: Hey, Just want to give an update on whats happening with all of the changes. I am running and grabbing metrics on all of our domains and will report back with how everything goes @sodawillow

Hopefully we wont be waiting a long time :)

Comment: Sorry that was directed to OP ... :) I think you should visit Code Review but for other reasons ... : ) @Mack keep me posted thanks : )

Comment: The script with just the switch (before the edit) ran in 4 hours and 16 minutes. I am running the memory management one currently and its closing in on 3+ hours

Comment: Was that with the latest update to my answer, or just the original suggestions and the `-Replace` change?

Comment: Your suggestions before the edit sorry for the confusion I edited my comment to reflect that, but the rewritten one is going on ~2.5 hours

Comment: With your suggestions and a bit more tinkering the script runs in about 30 min. 

The big save on time was putting the group objects into an array instead of a table and also filtering only the computers out of groups, there would sometimes be 300k+ groups which I did not realize when running on the larger servers. I will update the OP with the finalized code.

Thank you so much for your time! Also thank you @sodawillow

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the powershell version you have available (iirc you need PSv4), you might use the .where method on your lists, it is much faster:

```
$servs = $all_computers.where{$_ -match "Servers"} | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName
```

I suspect using select afterwards is also a tiny bit faster, but this is just guesswork.

Comment: actually using
    {$_ -eq "Servers"}
might be even faster ;)