# How can I improve this AD update powershell script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wrote this Powershell script years ago for updating AD from a CSV file.  I'd like to try to optimize to run quicker and without errors... but I'm not sure where to start / what could improve it.  Any suggestions are welcome.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\Employees.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
    Set-ADUser -EmployeeNumber $($user."EmployeeNumber") -Department $($user."Department") -Title $($user."Title") -Office $($user."office") -StreetAddress $($user."Address") -City $($user."City") -State $($user."State") -PostalCode $($user."PostalCode") -Company $($user."Company") -OfficePhone $($user."telephone") -Mobile $($user."cell") -Fax $($user."Fax")

Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($user.EmployeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{ExtensionAttribute1=($user.custom1); ExtensionAttribute2=($user.custom2); ExtensionAttribute3=($user.custom3); ExtensionAttribute4=($user.custom4)}
}
```

Comment: This might be better asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I'll ask over there.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Powershell-related traffic is extraordinarily light on CodeReview. The [powershell] tag is followed by only 100 people on CodeReview, whereas is followed by 19k on StackOverflow. Is it really worthwhile to refer a user there for what is really quite a small script?

Comment: @Jarrod provide a link to the code review question if/when you re-submit on that site. I have comments I'd be happy to add.

Comment: Here it is @veefu https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203252/powershell-script-that-updates-active-directory-user-information

Comment: @veefu - I was assuming that the users over at CodeReview would have a slightly different viewpoint and knowledgebase which would be more appropriate to spotting code inefficiencies - not that there aren't such people here, but I'd normally expect SO to be a more pragmatic "if it works without being inordinately bad performance, don't try to break it further".

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2cents worth on the topic... many can and will have different takes on it.
So, always good to wait for other opinions.

As for your baseline query...

> I'd like to try to optimize to run quicker and without errors

This is a very subjective thing.

1. What do you mean by optimize?
2. What do you mean by make it run quicker?

Why do you feel it is not optimal?
Why do you feel it's not quick enough?
What metrics did you use or what did you compare it against?

So, you need to decide what the above means to you and then be able to take a route that works. Because depending on what you are doing, and how, it will be fluid.

References:

[How to speed up PowerShell operations on AD objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396274/how-to-speed-up-powershell-operations-on-ad-objects)

[Weekend Scripter: PowerShell Speed Improvement Techniques](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/18/weekend-scripter-powershell-speed-improvement-techniques)

[Slow Code: Top 5 Ways to Make Your PowerShell Scripts Run Faster](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster)

[Coding for speed](https://foxdeploy.com/2016/03/23/coding-for-speed)

[Why cant PowerShell run loops fast ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anantd/2014/07/25/why-cant-powershell-run-loops-fast/)

All that being said...

I cannot come up with a reason, why you'd use Get-ADUser / Set-ADUser twice for the same getter data only your setter is different.  Do the get and set once. For large recordsets / data, loops are just slow. Remember, ADDS imposes limits on the number of records it will return at a time. If you are going after more than the default, you need to change that AD setting / request. If it is a large recordset, it's better to chunk it and break than into parallell operations on a smaller recordset. Take a look at parraller processing / workflows / runspaces for how to do that.